# Using Slack RTM API with Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, websocket, slack, slack-api

I am a beginner to the Django framework and I am building a Django app that uses the Slack RTM API.

I have a coded a program in python that performs the OAuth authentication process like so :

```
def initialize():
  url="https://slack.com/api/rtm.connect"
  payload={"token":"xxx"}
  r=requests.post(url,payload)
  res=json.loads(r.text)
  url1=res['url']
  ws = create_connection(url1)
  return ws
```

**My Requirement:**

The stream of events I receive (from my slack channel that my slack app is added to) is processed to filter out events of the type - message ,then match the message with a regex pattern and then store the matched string in a database.

As a stand alone python program I am receiving the stream of events from my channel.

**My questions:**

1. How do I successfully integrate this code to Django so that I can
   fulfill my requirement?
2. Do I put the code in templates/views? What is the
   recommended method    to process this stream of data?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def initialize():
  url = "https://slack.com/api/rtm.connect"
  r = requests.get(url, params={'token': '<YOUR TOKEN>'})
  res = r.json()
  url1=res['url']
  ws = create_connection(url1) #Note: There is no function called create_connnection() so it will raise an error
  return ws
```

if you read the API web methods, you see :

**Preferred HTTP method:** `GET`

See here: [Slack rtm.connect method](https://api.slack.com/methods/rtm.connect)

look at the comment, and thats the right code, see the differences between this code and yours.

basically to get JSON from a request don't use `json.loads` because this search your local computer not the request
use `r.json()` so it call the json you got from `r`.

Note that `r.text` will return raw text output so when you want to get url it will not be identified, with `r.json` you can call the object url as stated about

Hope this help.

and please could you tell us more what you wanna do with this in view ? because template is a directory which contains all the HTML files which you don't need to work with.

but why `views.py` ?